# return operator mechanic in the body of a function

Tags: javascript, return, reduce

Can someone please explain why the function is behaving differently in the following two scenarios? In the first scenario error is prompted saying 'arr.push is not a function'.

scenario 1

```
const arr = [1, 3, 11];

const doubled = arr.reduce((doubledArr, item) => {
   return doubledArr.push(item * 2);
}, []);

console.log(doubled);
```

scenario 2

```
const arr = [1, 3, 11];

const doubled = arr.reduce((doubledArr, item) => {
   doubledArr.push(item * 2);

   return doubledArr
}, []);

console.log(doubled);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first scenario you return the result of [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), which is the new [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value) of the object (the accumulator `array`) upon which the method was called. On the next iteration of [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), this `number` is provided as the accumulater and you try again to push a value to it. Since it's no longer an `array` but a `number`, you get the error `arr.push is not a function`.

The [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) callback should always return the accumulator, same as you did in scenario 2.